# DAX how to fill missing dates in range (Report builder)

Tags: date, dax, reportbuilder3.0

I have a table with 2 columns, date and score. It has at most 30 entries, for each of the last 30 days one.

| date | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1.8.2010 | 19 |
| 2.8.2010 | 21 |
| 4.8.2010 | 14 |
| 7.8.2010 | 10 |
| 10.8.2010 | 14 |

My problem is that some dates are missing - I want to see:

| date | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1.8.2010 | 19 |
| 2.8.2010 | 21 |
| 3.8.2010 | 0 |
| 4.8.2010 | 14 |
| 5.8.2010 | 0 |
| 6.8.2010 | 0 |
| 7.8.2010 | 10 |

What I need from the single query is to get: 19,21,9,14,0,0,10,0,0,14... That means that the missing dates are filled with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a date table and a YearMonth column :

[image]

```
ScoresALLDates = 
VAR ScoresMINDate = MIN(ScoresMD[date])
VAR ScoresMAXDate = MAX(ScoresMD[date])
VAR ScoresMINYearMonth = YEAR(ScoresMINDate) * 100 + MONTH(ScoresMINDate)
VAR ScoresMAXYearMonth = YEAR(ScoresMAXDate) * 100 + MONTH(ScoresMAXDate)
VAR DatesInRange = 
CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Dates[Date]),
    Dates[YearMonth]>=ScoresMINYearMonth,
    Dates[YearMonth]<=ScoresMAXYearMonth
    )
VAR FIllDatesWithoutScores = 
NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(
DatesInRange,
TREATAS(ScoresMD,Dates[Date],ScoresMD[score])
)
RETURN
FIllDatesWithoutScores
```